# Changes in web.xml for security not reflecting

Tags: java, glassfish

I want to make authorization in my java ee project, using realms. This is my code:

```
 <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/Views/agents/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>agent</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/Views/buyer/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/Views/seller/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/Views/property/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
```

This is my code in glassfish-web.xml

```
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

[image]

I made restart of glassfish, but it does not work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try smth like `mvn clean package`? It helps me sometimes